# Problem facing in reading file from Internal memory of android

Tags: android, memory, internal

I am facing the problem with openfileinput class.
First thing is , I am saving my username and password in the file.On sucessful login, I will be saving and moving to internal home screen.The problem is when I logout or close the application, and reopen the application I am able to read the data but when I convert it to String I get Out put as AAAAAA(each as 4 bytes). On succesful login on moving to Home screen , I am able to read it properly.I get this output before login.

This is something like , saving username and password in internal memory of android.

Regards:

Jayanth Gande

Comment: String data = "";
     try {
     data += userName.getText().toString() + " ";
     data += password.getText().toString() + " ";
     data += cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ";
     data += cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " ";
     data += cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " ";
    
     FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(TDCommons.FILENAME,
     MODE_PRIVATE);
     Log.i("Data writing into file", data);
     fos.write(data.getBytes());
     fos.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

Comment: byte[] filedata;
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(TDCommons.FILENAME);
filedata = new byte[fis.available()];
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(new String(filedata), " ");
if (fis.available() != 0) {
if (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
username = stk.nextToken();
}
if (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
pwd = stk.nextToken();
}
if (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
date = stk.nextToken();
}
if (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
month = stk.nextToken();
}
if (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
year = stk.nextToken();
}
fis.close();