# Creating Folder in Internal memory

Tags: android

I am unable to get the methods for creating folder in Internal Memory,

i gone through few conversations in [Android create folders in Internal Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory?rq=1)  and [Problem facing in reading file from Internal memory of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037037/problem-facing-in-reading-file-from-internal-memory-of-android?rq=1). But still i am unable to meet my requirement.

My requirement is , I want to create a folder in Internal Memory, there i want to Store one video.

Thankyou you very much in advance for valuable feedbacks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try the below

```
File mydir = context.getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
if (!mydir.exists())
{
     mydir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: I think the check if exists is not needed here. Base on the documentation: "The directory will have been created if it does not already exist."

Comment: if(!mydir.exists) should be **if(!mydir.exists())**

Comment: how do you then add a file to this specific dir?

Comment: what is it's path??

Comment: Can you please explain what `context` is?

Comment: Is context is variable or feild?

Comment: context is the current state of the application, use getApplicationContext() if not declared the context above in the activity or use getActivity() if using in fragments.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code which I am using for creating files in internal memory :

```
    File myDir = context.getFilesDir();
    // Documents Path
    String documents = "documents/data";
    File documentsFolder = new File(myDir, documents);
    documentsFolder.mkdirs(); // this line creates data folder at documents directory

    String publicC = "documents/public/api." + server;
    File publicFolder = new File(myDir, publicC);
    publicFolder.mkdirs(); // and this line creates public/api.myservername folder in internal memory
```

Comment: You have no clue how long I have been looking for this. Every time I would try it it would create the file outside of the files directory and it would append "app_" to the directory. +1 From me for the excelent, small and practical solution.

Comment: This creates the folder in internal memory but also in application package.

Answer (score 5):

To create directory on phone primary storage memory (generally internal memory) you should use following code. Please note that ExternalStorage in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not necessarily refers to sdcard, it returns phone primary storage memory

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyDirName");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Directory created using this code will be visible to phone user. The other method (as in accepted answer) creates directory in location (/data/data/package.name/app_MyDirName),  hence normal phone user will not be able to access it easily and so you should not use it to store video/photo etc.

You will need permissions, in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: **FALSE AND MISLEADING** - there is no such permission as android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: this answer is from May 2016, kindly check this permission with android version used that time. Android version changes so do their permissions. It will work in Android 5.0

Comment: **FALSE AGAIN**.  There has **never** been such an **internal** storage permission - to even suggest it is to betray a deep and fundamental misunderstanding of android filesystems.  The actual fact is that apps always have permission to **their own** internal storage folder.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder_name");

if(!direct.exists()) {
     if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a "cacheDirectory" in your "data/package_name" directory.

If you want to store something in that cache memory,

```
File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "temp");
if (!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdir();
```

where **this** is context.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    File cashDir = new File(dir.getCanonicalPath(),"folder");
    if(!(cashDir.exists())) cashDir.mkdirs();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your solution to OPs issue. One cannot make out what this yields