# How to create a folder in the phone memory (not SD card) in Android?

Tags: android, directory

I tried the following code to implement what I need

```java
File direct = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory() + "/YourFolder");

if (!direct.exists()) {
  if (direct.mkdir()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes make directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No make directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

I also added the following permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But it doesn't work. It just displays the toast message *"No make directory"*.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong or propose an alternate method to implement the same?

Comment: `But not works.` the most useless thing that you can say in software ;) - what does this mean?  Your app crashes?  The directory is not created?  The directory is created in the wrong place?  The sun stops shining?  Your cat died?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8124723/903469

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalDirectory()`, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this  link

[Creating Folder in Internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831051/creating-folder-in-internal-memory)

hopefully you are helpful from above link.

Best of luck!