# How to create file in the folder and write data to it

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, android-file

How to create folder (for example in the folder "Documents" in my phone), in this folder create the file and write data in this file? I have a code. But I am not shure that I do my file path is right. I want create folder and file not at SD card / I want do it in the device memory.

```
var filePath = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "myFolder/myFile.txt")
                filePath.mkdirs()
          
                try {
                    var outPut = FileOutputStream(filePath)
                    outPut.write("Hello")
                    outPut.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: This question has been asked a lot and you will find a lot of similar questions when you use Stack Overflow's search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate. This question answers how to create a file on the internal memory: [Android: how to write a file to internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587187/android-how-to-write-a-file-to-internal-storage). And this question answers how to create a folder on the internal memory: [How to create a folder in the phone memory (not SD card) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774730/how-to-create-a-folder-in-the-phone-memory-not-sd-card-in-android).