# Issue on creating folder in internal storage

Tags: android, storage

with the below code

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/ordinazioni";
```

I have created folder into storage/sdcard/.
But I want to create the same folder "ordinazioni" in internal storage.

Comment: above code create folder in internal storage

Comment: no, in external storage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15831051/7316510 refer to this link.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() create in external directory

Comment: and how can i create folder in internal storage?

Comment: run above code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37496667/6756514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Folder in Internal memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831051/creating-folder-in-internal-memory)

Comment: That does not create on SD card but on external storage. Which is IN your device and not removable. If you want to use internal private storage then use getFilesDir().

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a directory on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Though, it would be much better to use:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ordinazioni");
```

If you want to create a directory on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), replace `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in the above code snippet with a location for internal storage, such as `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` called on a `Context` (e.g., called on an `Activity` or `Service`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is well but its only the String of in path variable.
So with this same path String we will create a Folder or Directory:
Lets Do it here :

```
// Your code 
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                         .getAbsolutePath() + "/ordinazioni";
// After this
file=new File(path);
if(!file.isDirectory())
{    
    file.mkdirs();
}
```

Remember give Write Storage Permission if you are using Marsmallow then given Run time Permission also.

Now you issue is that you want to create it in Internal Storage so i want to say that this code made only for Internal storage for external you can do like this :

```
File newfile= new File("/sdcard/"+"ordinazioni");
```

But check your mobile have memory card or other External Drive.
I hope this will work for you