# How to create File In Internal Storage?

Tags: android

I read about it but I am unable to create a folder in internal storage that i can see it.

I have tried below code

```
 ContextWrapper contextwrapper=new ContextWrapper(MainActivity.this);
 File file=new File(getfiledir(),"namefile");
```

Comment: You say file in the title and folder in the question body. Which of the two do you really want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Folder in Internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831051/creating-folder-in-internal-memory)

Comment: `getfiledir()` ????????????

Comment: excuse me.folder @chade_

Answer (score 2):

Try this following, it's working fine.

```
   File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folderName");

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        String data="this is my first insert data";


        File myappFile=new File(file
                + File.separator + "myapp.txt");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myappFile);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
```

Must require these permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This creates a file in external storage as you can see.

Comment: `if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }`. Check the return value of mkdirs(). `if (!file.exists())
        {
            if ( !file.mkdirs()){ Toast(... sorry cannot create directory ...); return;} 
        }`

Comment: `Must require these permissions,`. You forget requesting permissions at runtime for Android 6+.