# how to navigate throught a directory in the internal storage

Tags: android, io

I already saw this question of creating a folder inside the internal storage [Creating Folder in Internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831051/creating-folder-in-internal-memory)
but how can I create a subfolder and get the list of files and folders stored inside that folder
Here is a thing I tried

```
val root=getDir("fold", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        root.mkdirs()
        val root1=getDir("fold\\a", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        root1.mkdirs()
        val root2=getDirs("fold\\b", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        root2.mkdir()
val x=root.listFiles().size
val y=root.list().size
```

but both the values of x and y are 0
which means either the directories are not created or (list or listFiles) are not used to retrieve the files and folders inside a directory

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\\` is not a directory separator on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.... to create a folder and keep it kept persistence I should use the `FILE` class instead.. like the following `val root=File(parentFile,fold);root.mkdirs()`  then every thing will work well